# Dynamically create controls at runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to create controls at runtime in C#. I use the method shown below:

Parse the XML file and get all the value from XML file, e.g.:

```
TextView.Name = DOC.SelectSingleNode("//TextViewObject/Name").InnerText;
TextView.Value = DOC.SelectSingleNode("//TextViewObject/Value").InnerText;
TextField.Name = DOC.SelectSingleNode("//TextFieldObject/Name").InnerText;
```

What method should I use to create controls at runtime? How can I get values from these controls?

Comment: Do you want to create control from your xml file? Please provide some more information..

Comment: @Sivaraman: yes i want to create controls from my XML